# Check if user liked my FB page on my external website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I know, that there are lot of questions with this error, but still I can't find solution for this error:

> Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

I'm working with this example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status == 'connected') {
            var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
            var page_id = "383152115092391"; //"383152115092391"; // coca cola page https://www.facebook.com/cocacola
            var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=" + page_id + " and uid=" + user_id;

            FB.api('/me/likes/'+page_id, function(response) {
                if (response.data[0]) {
                    $("#container_like").show();
                } else {
                    $("#container_notlike").show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            // user is not logged in
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mQ7Ny/)

And this is my DB app configuration:
[basic settings](http://uts.ic.cz/files/Has-user-liked-page_2014-03-30_21-48-46.png)
[advanced settings](http://uts.ic.cz/files/Has-user-liked-page_2014-03-30_21-49-13.png)

Can you please tell me, what am I missing?

Comment: I guess this is coming from the JS SDK. Apparently, you're running the website from another domain than you configured in the app's settings

Comment: I would add small advice .. at first, look at facebook developers page, where are official examples..

Lot of stuff on the internet are outdated and simply does not work.